# Update date within a table, Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm having trouble understanding on how to change the date on an update in postgres. What I have currently, that is giving a syntax error is

```
UPDATE works_locations SET (wrl_startdate = '2014-09-07', wrl_enddate = '2015-02-06')
```

with a few statements determining which field I should specifically change. However, postgres is giving me an error. How do I successfully change the date in postgres, even if the start date is around two years prior to this entry?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't have Postgres installed so I can't test this but try removing the parenthesis on your SET clause so that it looks like this:

```
UPDATE works_locations SET wrl_startdate = '2014-09-07', wrl_enddate = '2015-02-06'
```

Comment: Seems to have fixed it! Now I just got to go around and fix all my double quotes, thanks mate! EDIT: May I also ask as to why Postgres has this behaviour, if you know?

Comment: Your query did not follow the standard UPDATE query syntax. What database you were using where you had to put a parenthesis for the SET clause?

Comment: To be honest, I had no idea it was the correct syntax. The server I'm currently using is postgres! My mistake!